# Can't echo out the value of my input field with php?

Tags: php, html

I have a really basic problem and I can't find my mistake?

When I want to echo out `zone_field` (input field), i get this error: `Notice: Undefined index: zone_field in ...`

**HTML CODE**

```
<form action="./includes/insert_data.php" method="POST">

                <div id="zone_area">
                    <p><input type="text" value="test" name="zone_field" id="zone_field" placeholder="Enter a zone" autocomplete="off"></p>
                </div>
                <div id="button_area">
                    <p><input type="submit" value="Start" id="toggle_btn" name="toggle_btn"></p>
                </div>
</form>
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php

    include_once("./conn.php");

    echo $_POST['zone_field']; //can't echo out the value of the input 

 ?>
```

Comment: Is it perhaps disabled before submitting?

Comment: make sure the path in your form action is correct

Comment: When submitting i got this error message. I also tried only to echo out the zone_field but still got the same error. Undified Index...

Comment: @Jondreisbach It is. When i echo out something random it shows up on the screen but not the POST action

Comment: Have you confirmed that your form is submitted properly? Try doing `var_dump($_POST);` just before you check the values to see what has been submitted and let us know

Comment: @FluffyKitten I tried what you said. I can't see the zone_field and it's value. There is only one value (toggle_btn) in the output array but not the zone_field.

Comment: Do you have any javascript that does anything on form submissions? Are you posting it "normally" or through ajax?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes i do have a javascript function. I found my mistake. I do have a function in my code that toggles a btn (Start/Stop). Each time i change the button's value. I removed the function just for testing and now it works.